# Reading CSV files from zip archive with python-3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, zip

I have a zipped archive that contains several `csv` files.

For instance, assume `myarchive.zip` contains `myfile1.csv`, `myfile2.csv`, `myfile3.csv`

In `python 2.7` I was able to load iteratively all the `myfiles` in `pandas` using

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile(myarchive.zip, 'r') as zippedyear:
 for filename in ['myfile1.csv', 'myfile2.csv', 'myfile3.csv']:
     mydf = pd.read_csv(zippedyear.open(filename))
```

Now doing the same thing with `Python 3` throws the error

> ParserError: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open
>   the file in text mode?)

I am at a loss here. Any idea what is the issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strange indeed, since the only mode you can specify is `r/w` (character modes).

Here's a workaround; read the file using `file.read`, load the data into a `StringIO` buffer, and pass that to `read_csv`.

```
from io import StringIO

with zipfile.ZipFile(myarchive.zip, 'r') as zippedyear:
    for filename in ['myfile1.csv', 'myfile2.csv', 'myfile3.csv']:
         with zippedyear.open(filename) as f:
             mydf = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(f.read()))
```

Comment: thank you, very useful. do you know why it works now with a StringIO? what is it doing?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ read_csv _should_ accept any file or file like object, `StringIO` being one of them. All I did was read from the file normally and piped it into a string buffer, and had pandas read that. Just introduced a trusted middleman ;)

Comment: interesting. do you think this is related to this point maybe? https://webkul.com/blog/using-io-for-creating-file-object/

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Sorry, related to what?

Comment: have a look at the link in my comment my friend :)

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I mean, I did. That describes how StringIO works, yes. But what point are you asking is it related to?

Comment: nevermind buddy, its all good. thanks for the `StringIO` middleman!

Comment: Fwiw, I had to use `io.StringIO(f.read().decode())` to explicitly `decode()` the Bytes to a `str`. But I am using `csv.DictReader` instead of pd.