# How do I unzip multiple .gz files and output individual csv files contained in each of them?

Tags: gunzip

Non of the threads give a complete answer to this task.. I have multiple .gz files in one directory, I want to be able to extract all the csv files in each of them and output individual csv files. my code below runs without error, but does not unzip any file. I can't figure out where the problem is

```
#unzipping .gz files
import gzip
import shutil
import pandas as pd
import glob, os

for filename in glob.iglob('C:/Users/shedez/Documents/Data/**', recursive=True):
    if filename.endswith('gz'): # filter dirs
        with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f_in:
            with open('C:/Users/shedez/Documents/Data', 'wb') as f_out:
                shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50260054/4909087).

Comment: I am not actually reading the files, I just want to unzip them into same directory so that the next code can pick them up and concatenate. besides, I am dealing with gzip files

Comment: Why is this tagged as [pandas]?

Comment: It is actually a mistake, I took it off to avoid confusion